# PRAugmentedReality implementation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, augmented-reality

i'd try to add an AR function to my program to shows all location that i saved in an AR mode, i heard about [PRAugmentedReality](https://github.com/promet/PRAugmentedReality)
, did you guys ever implemented it in your project? if so, how do i set it up in my project? which data should i stored so PRAugmentedReality can work properly? did you guys had a simple code snippet so i can follow? kinda new with AR in objective-C. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know this sdk but if I can advise try Wikitude!

Comment: did using wikitude in my project require me to master the javascript language? if it didn't, can you provide me with a simple step by step guide how to implement wikitude in my project, Thank you sir!